# JS Switch statement is ignored

Tags: javascript, scope, switch-statement

```js
fileType = document.getElementById('file-type-select');

fileType.addEventListener('change', function() {
  setFileName(this.value);
});

setFileName();

function setFileName(fileType = 0) {
  file = (function() {
    let name = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "");

    switch (fileType) {
      case 1:
        name += '.txt';
        break;
      case 2:
        name += '.md';
        break;
      case 3:
        name += '.html';
        break;
      default:
        name += '.txt';
    }

    return {
      'name': name,
    }
  })();

  console.log(file.name);
}
```

```html
<select id="file-type-select" name="file-type">
  <option value="1">Plain text</option>
  <option value="2">Markdown</option>
  <option value="3">HTML source</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, in the `setFileName` function, the switch statement always goes to default and `file.name` always ends with .txt

Why is this? I'm guessing is something with the scope of the argument but can't tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `setFileName` function, the function parameter `fileType` is `string` value, not `number` value.

And on `switch` command, you have done the comparation with number values and it should be changed to compare with `string` values as follows and it will work.

```js
fileType = document.getElementById('file-type-select');

fileType.addEventListener('change', function() {
  setFileName(this.value);
});

setFileName();

function setFileName(fileType = 0) {
  file = (function() {
    let name = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "");

    switch (fileType) {
      case '1':
        name += '.txt';
        break;
      case '2':
        name += '.md';
        break;
      case '3':
        name += '.html';
        break;
      default:
        name += '.txt';
    }

    return {
      'name': name,
    }
  })();

  console.log(file.name);
}
```

```html
<select id="file-type-select" name="file-type">
  <option value="1">Plain text</option>
  <option value="2">Markdown</option>
  <option value="3">HTML source</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or wrap `fileType` with `Number()`